# Inkscape - How to cut lines across an arc?

Tags: inkscape

I need to cut these lines across the arc.  I only need the little itty bitty line ends.  The arc and long parts of the lines are to be discarded.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step 1

In order to use the circle to trim the line paths, you must select the circle and convert it to a path by clicking **Path > Object to Path** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on Windows

Step 2

Select all paths except the circle and go to Path > Combine or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> ; this allows you to perform boolean operations on the group of lines.

[image]

Step 3

Make sure the circle is above your lines with Object > Raise to Top. Then select all paths and go to Path > Cut path or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> This will cut the combined group along the perimeter of your circle.

[image]

Step 4

Finally, you can select each line trimming and delete them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to make this with the detail of explanation.

Comment: No problem @STWilson :) the gif recorder makes things quick. It's helpful to think of the boolean operations like arithmetic; this is reflected in the keyboard shortcuts also as they use +,-,/ etc. For e.g. CTRL and "+" is "Unify".

Comment: How I looked for this answer on the several internet sites. Very good indeed ... It will help a lot of people. Thank you for helping me too ...