# Inkscape - trimming filled paths along an arc

Tags: inkscape, path

I've got a task somewhat similar to a previously-posed question (1), but not so similar that it solves my problem!

I've got a sunburst (radial treemap) with four concentric layers of text. (These are generated online fom a JSON file, so I haven't got access to the workings.)

As you can see, three of the layers are a lot wider than is needed to fit the text. So I'm reworking the SVG to trim the excess from each ring of radials.

When I use the method described in (1), I can only trim one radial at a time, which means making more than 50 iterations of the sequence. Or I can *combine* all the radials, thereby losing all the colour fill.

[image]

I have made an arched path to lay over the area I want to remove, then used *exclusion* to remove part of one radial at a time. Whenever I use it on more than one radial at a time, all the colour information disappears.

Likewise, the *division* operation seems to have no effect.

*Scaling* the radials creates other problems - though I suppose one might find a way to scale in one direction only.

I am supposing there are other ways to peel this banana. What will work?

Am I going to run into problems regardless? (Given the limitation of only one point of intersection, or the loss of colour info in combining paths.)

1. [Inkscape - How to cut lines across an arc?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94136/inkscape-how-to-cut-lines-across-an-arc?newreg=35a548ea1b3a4cfda8783d004817afc5)

Comment: Why wouldn't you program this?

Comment: Program in what sense? I'm not a credible code writer.

Comment: Try this extension to cut multiple objects at once: https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-pathops

Comment: Thanks Moini. I've installed it but haven't got it to work. Have you got any tips about that?

Comment: Possible hints: Have you read and followed the instructions? Are your objects grouped?

Comment: And, can you clarify what you mean by 'haven't got it to work', please?

Comment: Yeah, I did read, and no, I haven't grouped. But I also did some more googling, and found a) that the extension may never complete when running on Windows 64-bit (that's me!) and b) that there's a similar extension here (https://github.com/quintesse/inkscape-extension-pathops) that I've just used successfully. So I think the inx-pathops version ought to be limited to 32-bit systems.

Comment: I did something similar with this: https://inkscape.org/de/~Moini/%E2%98%85multi-bool-extension-cut-difference-division to change more than 2 paths