# Begginer, how to 'cut' a circle in Inkscape an achieve pie like pieces?

Tags: inkscape

I am completely green with Inkscape and graphics. As an exercise I am trying to create my own coffee wheel, which looks something like that:

[image]

I struggle with creating these circle fragments. So far I managed to create a circle with a hole by differencing two circles and then cut a few of such slices by intersecting that "donut" with a triangle (I may screw effects names a little bit, because I don't work on the English version myself).

This works but seems cumbersome. Also, calculating correct sizes and degrees is difficult. Any simple solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Michal. You can generate the sunburst chart (e.g. [here](https://www.aculocity.com/labs/sunburst-chart) or [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/sunburst-chart/)) and export it. To cut the circle, see [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94136/inkscape-how-to-cut-lines-across-an-arc), or [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119687/inkscape-trimming-filled-paths-along-an-arc) or [similar](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69868/how-do-i-split-a-circle-into-equal-sections-in-inkscape). Try, and update us!

Comment: Hi @PaoloGibellini! Thank you for your comment, if you post is as an answer I can upvote it and mark your answer as correct :) I will try it in the evening or tomorrow when I am back to work on this project!

Comment: Hi, Michal, my comment is not a properly answer. I suggest you to make your attempts, write your own answer and mark is as correct: it would be a more effective answer.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I love this reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @Paolo Gibellini for the good advice!

I probably choose a cumbersome approach, but I find it good for practising and kinda rewarding:

1. I create a donut, by creating two overlapping circles and Path Subtracting them.
2. I create a straight line starting in the middle and piercing the circle. This is faced up at point 0 degrees.
3. I duplicate and rotate this line using Ctrl (then it jumps by 15 degrees, but it is customizable).
4. Finally I cut the donut using Path Division.

If you want to do so, remember to first cut your donut in half and then cut out particular pieces! The shape you cut must be cut throughout or it will not work. For much awesome materials, check comments under the original post!